# Automatic Shift Planner in Excel using Conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I want to figure out how to schedule shifts automatically in Excel (Native)

What I'm trying to achieve is this (Attached will help you visualize):

Screenshot describing what I have and what I want to achieve for a better visualization

[image]

I want to have 2 variables: Start Date and Shift Frequency (Once every)

These 2 variables will be the input that will determine the start date of the shifts (from 1 to 31, with 1 being the first day of the month and 31 being the last day of the month)

Once those are determined and fed to Excel, Using Conditional Formatting, I want to fill the Cells that satisfy the function above.

This is the Final Function I came up with (FOR EMPLOYEE 1) but it didn't work

```
=MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("B"&$H$3);$G$3)=1
```

- `INDIRECT("B"&$H$3)` Could be = B1, B2, ..., B31
- `ROW(INDIRECT("B"&$H$3))` = The starting point for Employee 1 (Filling
  the shifts starting from this point/row in the table)
- `$G$3` = The Frequency with which we should fill the table

I don't know where I went wrong.

I'm open to your suggestion or if there's a tool that can do the same without excel. But I would prefer to do it in native Excel

Answer (score 0):

Let’s evaluate your formula:

- `=MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("B"&$H$3);$G$3)=1`
- `=MOD(ROW(INDIRECT("B4”);$G$3)=1`
- `=MOD(ROW(4;3)=1`
- Huh?

There’s a missing “)” but even if present the logic wouldn’t be right.

I would **HIGHLY** recommend placing your formula logic *in the cells* and not in the conditional formatting rules.  An accidental circular reference in the cells causes an error.  An accidental circular reference in a conditional formatting rule can and often does corrupt the worksheet.

So…

`=ROW()` returns the row number of the current row.  `=ROW()` in cell B5 returns 5.

I think you want `=IF(AND(ROW()>=$H$3;MOD(ROW()-$H$3;$G$3)=0,xxx,””)` in cell B2, then copied down.  `xxx` is whatever you want to appear in the cell if it matches, for instance it could be `“*”`.  You then use a simple `=“*”` formula for conditional formatting to apply a color to the cell.

Comment: Thank you so much @max It worked, I changed my approach from Conditional Formatting to using as you suggested the formula inside the cell to display "TRUE" or "FALSE" and then used conditional formatting to color in each outcome.